# Change the dimmed background in UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view that loads data from a database stored with Core Data using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. I implemented a `UISearchController` and I want it to dim the background showing the non-filtered table view when the search bar is selected and is empty and to show the results scrollable when some text is present.

I tried to change the `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation` property of the `UISearchController`, and it works until I change this value only in the `viewWillAppear` function. But when I tried to change the property based on the status of the search bar text the background remains always dimmed.

This is my `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` function:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let searchText = self.searchController.searchBar.text {
        var scope: String = ""
        let scopeButton = searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex
        switch scopeButton {
        case 0:
            scope = "cardName"
        case 1:
            scope = "minionType.type"
        case 2:
            scope = "tagAbility.ability"
        default:
            scope = ""
        }

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: scope + " contains[c] %@", searchText)
        filteredCards = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.filter() {
            return searchPredicate.evaluateWithObject($0)
            } as? [Card]

        filteredSections = evaluateSectionsAfterSearch(filteredCards)

        if searchText.isEmpty {
            self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
            self.searchControl = false
        } else {
            self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            self.searchControl = true
        }
        print(self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The searchControl variable is used to determine which array the table view must load when I call the `reloadData` function.
I can't find out why the background remains dimmed, the `print` command shows that the value is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation` only effect the next present, there is no way to turn it on/off when the searchController have been presented